# Re-install mac software

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mac-mini

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade to Snow Leopard without a CD drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/35108/how-do-i-upgrade-to-snow-leopard-without-a-cd-drive)

I am the proud owner of a new mac mini, however!

I may have been sold a pup as the previous owner has overwritten the osx software with windows.  My question is, how do I re-install the mac software, as I have no drive.

Note. I do have a windows laptop and a snow leopard install disc.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to Snow Leopard without a CD drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/35108/how-do-i-upgrade-to-snow-leopard-without-a-cd-drive) also check out: http://superuser.com/questions/351170/can-i-do-a-fresh-install-of-snow-leopard-from-external-dvd-drive, http://superuser.com/questions/230123/is-there-a-way-to-perform-an-install-of-osx-from-a-flash-drive, http://superuser.com/questions/96283/how-to-upgrade-os-on-mac-mini-with-external-usb-drive for some (more) ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to reinstall OS X:

- Get an external DVD drive and reinstall using your install disc - you can follow the instructions in the [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/351183), which was derived from this [Apple manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Snow_Leopard_Installation_Instructions.pdf)
- Reinstall from a USB drive - there are more detailed instructions on [this article](http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html), but you'll need a 8+ GB USB drive to load the Snow Leopard install files
- Remote install from another PC or Mac - more detailed instructions are contained within these two Apple KBs ([one](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2129) and [two](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5287)).

Since you already have an install disc, getting an external DVD drive and reinstalling using the Snow Leopard install disc is likely to be the easiest method.

Comment: You can also use a PC as the install disk host.  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2129

Comment: @ChrisNava, good point - I'll update my answer